# Make an Array from JSON object values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this simple JSON file (test.json):

```
{"personnes":[
            {
                "name":"Super",
                "firstname":"Mario",
                "adresse":["45 rue du poirier","6700","Strasbourg"],
                "departement": "bas-rhin",
            },
            {
                "name":"Super",
                "firstname":"Luigi",
                "adresse":["10 rue du muguet","6700","Strasbourg"],
                "departement": "eure",
            }
]}
```

For some reasons, I need to get each "departement" values to be stored in a single array like this :*`["bas-rhin","eure"]`*

I learned that *`$.makeArray()`* can do the job, but didn't find out how. Here is my jQuery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
        console.log('loaded');
        var departement;
        var departements = $.each(data.personnes, function (index, personne) {
            departement = personne.departement;
            var arr = $.makeArray(departement);
            console.log(arr)
        });
    });
});
```

With that code, I get 2 seperate arrays : `["eure"]` and `["bas-rhin"]`.

**Here is the question : *How can I solve it and get these values in a single array ?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should try like this:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    console.log('loaded');
    var departement = []; // create array here
    $.each(data.personnes, function (index, personne) {
        departement.push(personne.departement); //push values here
    });
    console.log(departement); // see the output here
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It's much simpler:

```
var arr = data.personnes.map(function (el) {
  return el.departement;
});

console.log(arr); // ["bas-rhin", "eure"]
```

Alternatively, using jQuery's [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var arr = $.map(data.personnes, function (el) {
  return el.departement;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/QxpZW/)

If you need a polyfill for map:

```
if (!('map' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.map = function (mapper, that /*opt*/) {
    var other = new Array(this.length);
    for (var i = 0, n = this.length; i < n; i++) {
      if (i in this) { other[i] = mapper.call(that, this[i], i, this); }
    }
    return other;
  };
}
```

Comment: Its fine but ie8 is having issues with .map().

Comment: You could use $.map for a more compatible solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are many to declare a array. choose any one:

```
var arr = $.makeArray();
or
var arr = [];
or
var arr = new Array();
```

There are listed three way to create array from json object:

1.

```
$.each(data.personnes, function (index, personne) {
    arr[index] = personne.departement;
});
```

2.

```
var arr = personnes.personnes.map(function (element) {
    return element.departement;
});
```

3.

```
for(var index = 0;  index < data.personnes.length; index++) {
    arr[arr.length] = data.personnes[index].departement;
}
```

Now you have look on image :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
        console.log('loaded');
        var departement_arr = [];
        var departements = $.each(data.personnes, function (index, personne) {
            departement_arr.push(personne.departement);
        });
        console.log(departement_arr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have associative arrays; you can only push a value into an array. If you are looking for the following end result:

```
   ['abc','dg','erte']
```

//  0     1    2     <------- Index ( not 1  2  3 )

use .each

```
var arr= new Array();
$.each( personnes, function(i, obj) {
      arr.push( obj.personnes)
});
```

Or you could use .map

```
var arr = $.map( personnes, function( obj, i ) { return obj.personnes; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using simple array logic:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
        console.log('loaded');
        var departements = [];
        $.each(data.personnes, function (index, personne) {
            departements[departements.length] = personne.departement;
        });
        console.log(arr);
    });
});
```